# boost python expose and import methods time cost

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am experiencing a difficulty using boost python facilities to extend my C++ code to Python. I've written the boost.python wrappers successfully. I also have access to my C++ objects from Python without any error, in addition called a Python file (module) method from C++ using boost attr("")() function without any problem.

My problem is the execution time of the Python method. Referencing to the wrapped objects are about microseconds in Python code as I've printed. Although the time calling the Python method takes is about milliseconds and it increases with respect to the number of references I've made in the Python to my wrapped C++ objects (and only referencing/assigning not any further use). Thus I've made some search and my assumptions about this increasing time is:

1. some reference policies (default policies) causes this problem by doing some unnecessary operation(s) when returning from the Python code. So probably I'm doing something wrong in the wrappers.
2. Boost.Python call method has some overhead, which there might be some options I'm not aware of.

It worth mentioning that the Python method called in each execution cycle of my program and each time I get a very same (not exact) time.

I hope my description were enough. Below is also a part of my sample code:

One of my Wrappers:

```
class_<Vertex<> >("Vertex")
  .def(init<float, float>())
  .def_readwrite("x", &Vertex<>::x)
  .def_readwrite("y", &Vertex<>::y)
  .def("abs", &Vertex<>::abs)
  .def("angle", &Vertex<>::angle)
  .def(self - self)
  .def(self -= self)
;
```

Calling a Python module method (which is "run"):

```
pyFile = import(fileName.c_str());
scope scope1(pyFile);
object pyNameSpace = scope1.attr("__dict__");
return extract<int>(pyFile.attr("run")());
```